# GUI problem 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to make my first GUI but I keep running into weird problems I haven't seen before it's been 2 days, can anyone help.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os.path

file_list_column = ((sg.Text("Image Folder"), sg.In(size=(25,1), enable_events=True, key="-FOLDER-"), sg.FolderBrowse(),)(sg.Listbox(values=(), enable_events=True, size=(40,20), key="-FILE LIST-")))

image_viewer_column = ((sg.Text("Choose an image from the list on the left:")),(sg.Text(size=(40,1), key=("-TOUT-")),(sg.Image(key="-IMAGE-"))))

layout= [[sg.Column(file_list_column),sg.VSeperator(),sg.Colmn(image_viewer_column)]]

window = sg.Window("Image Viewer", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback *in the question* not as a comment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have really not seen an error message like this before, it is a warning sign that you have not spent enough time studying the fundamentals before trying to create your own GUI program. You should, before branching out like this, have learned some basic [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) skills, which include reading error messages and trying to relate them to the code. For example, what do you think this message means? Which tuple do you think it is talking about? How do you figure the code is trying to "call" it?

Comment: I have never used PySimpleGUI, but it's clear to me that there are multiple typos in this code. Please try to be more careful. Consider trying to put less code on a line, so that you can see the structure more clearly. Think carefully about what you are typing, including spelling.

Comment: There are two common causes of this error: 1) Using `()` when you should be using `[]`. 2) Assigning a built-in function name as a variable.

Comment: Hint: look closely around this part of the code: `sg.FolderBrowse(),)(sg.Listbox(values=()`

Answer (score 0):

```py
file_list_column = (
    (
        sg.Text("Image Folder"),
        sg.In(size=(25,1), enable_events=True, key="-FOLDER-"),
        sg.FolderBrowse(),
    )   # A comma missed here
    (
        sg.Listbox(values=(), enable_events=True, size=(40,20), key="-FILE LIST-")
    )
)
```

A comma missed and it is something like this

```py
>>> ((1, 2, 3)(4,))
<interactive input>:1: SyntaxWarning: 'tuple' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```